# Configure Onesignal with Nativescript (with javascript)

Tags: push-notification, nativescript, onesignal

I´m creating an app with nativescript and i need push notifications, so i read about onesignal and it looks promissing, so i have created an account with them, follow the instructions for ios, then they sent you [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-onesignal) where you are suppose to configure the nativescript SDK for your mobile app. Well, i´m not using typescript, so my first question is:

- Where is the javascript version to configure the nativescript SDK,
  does anyone knows?

My second question is related with the data that my app receives, which is throught a database, i have a webapp and everytime a user INSERTS in the database, a listview in the nativescript app is "fed"...but when this happens, **i need the script from onesginal to send the push** does anyone ever used it?

Thanks for your time
   Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. TypeScript makes it easy to maintain large scale JavaScript applications, NativeScript or Angular itself is written in TypeScript for same reason. So personally I would recommend getting started with TypeScript for better.

If you want to convert TypeScript into JavaScript, simply remove all typings from your code, replace import statements with `require`. At least this should work in NativeScript environment as it supports most of ES6 syntaxes. If you prefer ES5, simply use any online compiler to get JS version of same code, [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html) for instance.

Also NativeScript [docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/application-lifecycle#ios-uiapplicationdelegate) got examples for extending app delegate in JavaScript if you need further guidance on this.

2. I don't think the plugin provides any interface to handle notification data at the moment. If you are familiar with the native apis, you may directly access them from JavaScript to access the data sent from server. If possible, I would recommend migrating to [Firebase](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase) which supports end to end integration with proper examples.

Comment: @manoj,do firebase has support for ES5 ? I do not think so.  I have digging on FCM web push notifications  and I could not find a single example in ES5.

Comment: ES5 / ES6 depends on compiler target, {N} runtime already supports E6. Firebase plugin doesn't decide anything here.